# Difference between the runtime of Dijkstra's Algorithm: Priority Queue vs. Doubly Linked List

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, priority-queue, dijkstra, doubly-linked-list

What is the difference, regarding runtime complexity, between the following and why?:

**(1) DIJKSTRA's algorithm using regular Priority Queue (Heap)**

**(2) DIJKSTRA's algorithm using a doubly linked list**

(Unless there isn't a difference)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time

Comment: Disagree with "off topic" close; clearly this is topical, as witnessed by the plethora of relevant tags defined by StackOverflow, which are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The most general version of Dijkstra's algorithm assumes that you have access to some sort of priority queue structure that supports the following operations:

- make-heap(s, n): build a heap of n nodes at initial distance ∞, except for the start node s, which has distance 0.
- dequeue-min(): remove and return the element with the lowest priority.
- decrease-key(obj, key): given an existing object *obj* in the priority queue, reduce its priority to the level given by *key*.

Dijkstra's algorithm's requires one call to make-heap, O(n) calls to dequeue-min, and O(m) calls to decrease-key, where n is the number of nodes and m is the number of edges. The overall runtime can actually be given as O(T<sub>m-h</sub> + nT<sub>deq</sub> + mT<sub>d-k</sub>), where T<sub>m-h</sub>, T<sub>deq</sub>, and T<sub>d-k</sub> are the average (amortized) costs of doing an make-heap, a dequeue, and a decrease-key, respectively.

Now, let's suppose that your priority queue is a doubly-linked list. There's actually several ways you could use a doubly-linked list as a priority queue: you could keep the nodes sorted by distance, or you could keep them in unsorted order. Let's consider each of these.

In a sorted doubly-linked list, the cost of doing a make-heap is O(n): just insert the start node followed by n - 1 other nodes at distance infinity. The cost of doing a dequeue-min is O(1): just delete the first element. However, the cost of doing a decrease-key is O(n), since if you need to change a node's priority, you may have to move it, and you can't find where to move it without (in the worst case) doing a linear scan over the nodes. This means that the runtime will be O(n + n + nm) = O(mn).

In an unsorted doubly-linked list, the cost of doing a make-heap is still O(n) because you need to create n different nodes. The cost of a dequeue-min is now O(n) because you have to do a linear scan over all the nodes in the list to find the minimum value. However, the cost of a decrease-key is now O(1), since you can just update the node's key in-place. This means that the runtime is O(n + n<sup>2</sup> + m) = O(n<sup>2</sup> + m) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), since the number of edges is never more than O(n<sup>2</sup>). This is an improvement from before.

With a binary heap, the cost of doing a make-heap is O(n) if you use the standard linear-time heapify algorithm. The cost of doing a dequeue is O(log n), and the cost of doing a decrease-key is O(log n) as well (just bubble the element up until it's in the right place). This means that the runtime of Dijkstra's algorithm with a binary heap is O(n + n log n + m log n) = O(m log n), since if the graph is connected we'll have that m ≥ n.

You can do even better with a Fibonacci heap, in an asymptotic sense. It's a specialized priority queue invented specifically to make Dijkstra's algorithm fast. It can do a make-heap in time O(n), a dequeue-min in time O(log n), and a decrease-key in (amortized) O(1) time. This makes the runtime of Dijkstra's algorithm O(n + n log n + m) = O(m + n log n), though in practice the constant factors make Fibonacci heaps slower than binary heaps.

So there you have it! The different priority queues really do make a difference. It's interesting to see how "Dijkstra's algorithm" is more of a *family* of algorithms than a single algorithm, since the choice of data structure is so critical to the algorithm running quickly.

Comment: as a footnote I think its important to add that the binary heap implementation is not always faster because m can potentially equal n^2 in which case the complexity is O(n^2 log n)